# split_part function from nth split till end of string

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

After the second space, I need to fetch the values till the particular position in the string.
Source:

```
"8 115 MACKIE STREET VICTORIA PARK WA 6100 AU"  
"6A CAMBOON ROAD MORLEY WA 6062 AU"
```

output:

```
"MACKIE STREET VICTORIA PARK"
"CAMBOON ROAD MORLEY"
```

I'm trying to split the street name and suburb from the unit #,street# present in the beginning and the state, postcode, country present in the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
t=# with s(v) as (values('6A CAMBOON ROAD MORLEY WA 6062 AU'),('8 115 MACKIE STREET VICTORIA PARK WA 6100 A'))
, split as (select *,count(1) over (partition by v) from s, regexp_matches(v,'( [A-Z]+)','g') with ordinality t(m,o))
select distinct v,string_agg(m[1],'') over (partition by v) from split where o <= count-(3-1);
                      v                      |          string_agg
---------------------------------------------+------------------------------
 8 115 MACKIE STREET VICTORIA PARK WA 6100 A |  MACKIE STREET VICTORIA PARK
 6A CAMBOON ROAD MORLEY WA 6062 AU           |  CAMBOON ROAD MORLEY
(2 rows)
```

I excluded index (or any not fitting mask `[A-Z]+`) thus cutting not three positions from the end, but two `(3-1)` where 1 is ahead known index.

Also I start not from the second space as it would be against your desired result...